# Type 'string' is not assignable to type Inside Object (Only vscode)

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, types

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but I still cannot figure out how I can achieve this without casting it and losing all the type safety I want.

I have two types:

```
type ThisIsMyType = {
  propA: string,
  propB: { 
    propInsideB1: boolean,
    propInsideB2: AnotherType
  }
};

type AnotherType = 'Test' | 'Testing';
```

When I try to assign a variable with that type I get a type error:

```
const myArrayItems: ThisIsMyType[] = [
  { 
    propA: 'just a string',
    propB: { 
      propInsideB1: true,
      propInsideB2: 'Test' 
    } 
  }
]
```

The error I get is:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AnotherType'

I don't want to cast it like `'Test' as AnotherType` because then I can just type 'BLA' and it doesn't give a type error / warning.

How can I fix this?

UPDATE:
I cannot reproduce the issue in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwM4EkkFkQ3NAvFAbwFgAoKKMAJwHswBBALiiWEoQDsBzAGlPKtoAhJgSh9yFGmBTskCACYRBARiYAjatQA2EAIbteZCQOmyFSgExM67asDgRK2SOIC+pVwG5SpUJCg2dg5OOFD4AOQwECzhUAA+UJHRwByc4d4kpADG1LLAUAC2IHSUlLogKMAQBUhM8MhomM4QANoAumFQLeKi4vxSjIkAVgCuLFC6zKyp4YYSkkIiYkbzJjJyiipMrCMQc-MLphuWTEkxy-OuF1DuJG2kQA), but only in VSCode.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwM4EkkFkQ3NAvFAbwFgAoKKMAJwHswBBALiiWEoQDsBzAGlPKtoAhJgSh9yFGmBTskCACYRBARiYAjatQA2EAIbteZCQOmyFSgExM67asDgRK2SOIC+pVwG5SpUJCg2dg5OOFD4AOQwECzhUAA+UJHRwByc4d4kpADG1LLAUAC2IHSUlLogKMAQBUhM8MhomM4QANoAumFQLeKi4vxSjIkAVgCuLFC6zKyp4YYSkkIiYkbzJjJyiipMrCMQc-MLphuWTEkxy-OuF1DuJG2kQA)

Comment: Use an enum: `enum AnotherType { Test = 'test', ... }`, then you can write `propInsideB2: AnotherType.Test`. Another option is to use the `const` cast: `propInsideB2: 'Test' as const`, I think it could work and save yourself to typing "BLA" and it doesn't give the error.

Comment: Hmm indeed.. In the playground I can't reproduce it either.. Maybe it is just a setting in vscode or in the tsconfig file...

Comment: If the enum is the only option... But I'm not a big fan of enums